# Unity button onClick event trigger has a noticeable delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why does my button's onClick function have a small but noticeable delay? I'm calling a function from the buttons built in onClick function that starts an animation. This animation starts but with a noticeable delay.

Calling the function by checking Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) in the update function removes this delay and the animation starts immediately.

So I've made the conclusion that the buttons OnClick function is the problem, but I can't seem to find online anyone that has this same problem. How do I fix this delay?

Delay:
[image]

No Delay:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        explosionWave.Detonate();
    }
}
```

I'm using Unity 2017.1.1

Solution:

Thank you for this @Lelefant , didn't realize OnClick was called at mouseUp. But still, find it strange that mouseUp also had this same delay. Either way, this fixed the issue:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class OnPointerDownExplode : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler// required interface when using the OnPointerDown method.
{
    public ExplosionWave explosionWave;

    //Do this when the mouse is clicked over the selectable object this script is attached to.
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        explosionWave.Detonate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you a lot of UI elements in your scene? Make sure all the UI element that does not need to be clicked has the `raycastTarget` flag set to **false** (text, raw images, images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button.OnClick` event triggered called at mouseUp.
You could attach a script to the button that implements the `IPointerDownHandler` if you don't like to check during `Update()`.

Keep in mind that *onClick* allows the user to drag the pointer out of the button to cancel the action, while *onPointerDown* starts the action immediately.